# Javascript - How to store ID against indexOf of array when pushing data to an array and removing?

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, multidimensional-array

I'm building up an array of socket.ids and trying to get a 'temporary' id for them by getting the array index as being the 'temporary' ID.

I am currently building my array as follows:

```
let serving_point_key = serving_points.indexOf(socket.id);
if (serving_point_key === -1) {
    serving_points.push(socket.id);
    serving_point_key = serving_points.indexOf(socket.id);
}
let serving_point_id = serving_point_key + 1;
```

and I am removing the items from the array as:

```
 let serving_point_key = serving_points.indexOf(socket.id);
    if (serving_point_key !== -1) {
        serving_points.splice(serving_point_key, 1);
    }
```

The issue I'm having is that if there is 3 items in the array, and I remove the second for example, the index of the third item is now 1 less, therefore the logic of using indexOf to get an 'temporary' ID is flawed when I try and get the "ID" for the socket user as it's changed as soon as I remove an item before it in the array?

Is there anyway to keep the index when I push to an array, so that the index is kept when removing? maybe using a multi dimensional array? or would it be best to use objects?

Any help or advice would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: it is a very bad idea to use indexOf as an id (even if it is temporary).. what is socket.id, can't you use that as the temp id?

Comment: socket.id is the ID of the socket user, something like (Oej3ULC2QL98GNaCAAA) but need to have a INT ID like 1, 2, 3

Comment: why does the temp id need to be an integer? it is easier to just map the elements in serving_points array as object with socketId.. ex: serving_points = [{value: 'abc', socketId: Oej3ULC2QL98GNaCAAA}]; and you can splice it by getting the index using findIndex(serving_points, (serving_point) => servingPoint.socketId === socket.id);

Answer (score 0):

I've updated the logic to push an object to the array and store the ID.

```
let serving_point_key = serving_points?.findIndex(sp => sp.socket_id === socket.id);

    if (serving_point_key === -1) {
        
        let id = null;
        if (serving_points.length === 0) {
            id = 1;
        } else {
            for( var i = 0; i < serving_points.length; i++ ) {
                let id_exists = (serving_points?.findIndex(sp => sp.id === (i + 1)) !== -1);
                if (id_exists === false) {
                    id = (i + 1);
                }
            }
            console.log(id);
            if (id === null) {
                id = serving_points.length + 1;
            }
        }

        let sp_data = {
            'id': id,
            'socket_id': socket.id
        }

        serving_points.push(sp_data);
        serving_point_key = serving_points?.findIndex(sp => sp.socket_id === socket.id);
    }
    let serving_point_id = serving_points[serving_point_key].id;
```